# IceCast SSL certificate as not secure

Tags: ssl, apache2, icecast

I have installed on my server IceCast with SSL. The program works perfectly but the SSL certificate is recognized as non-secure in the browser. I generated the certificate with the following code:

> openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout icecast2.pem -out icecast2.pem

Page capture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YhP5.png

Does anyone know how I can fix it?

PD: I´m running Apache2 Server and Debian.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a self-signed certificate that is [not contained in any trustchain](https://serverfault.com/questions/363707/are-self-signed-ssl-certificates-secure). Hence, it is marked as insecure by your browser.

There is hardly any way to fix this with your existing certificate. You can try through the [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) initiative.

Comment: Note that Icecast expects a combined certificate file, so you'll need to concat private key and public key generated by your Let's encrypt client.

Comment: Can you explain how to generate a certificate with let's encrypt for icecast? Thanks.

Comment: @ChoiZ Due to the q&a-nature of this site, I'd recommend opening a separate question for that.